# How to sort items in a list in Angular?

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I'm creating an option selector, were you're able to select options for a certain machine. See image with a design of the objects:

**Object:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
export class Machine{
    Id: string;
    MachineGroup: MachineGroup;
    Price: number;
    Description: string;
    Image: Image;
    Weight: number;
    Power: number;
    Speed: number;
    Name: string;
    BomId: number;
    Options: Option[];
}

export class Option{
    Id: number;
    Price: number;
    OptionGroup: OptionGroup;
    Description: string;
}

export class OptionGroup{
    Id: number;
    Image: Image;
    Name: string;
}
```

The options need to be sorted under their OptionGroup, is there some kind of LINQ I can use within Angular?

I mean I can make a function within the component which loops though the list of options and add those objects to a new list to show. But this gave an undefined error, while the component isn't rendered before the Machine is set. The console.log printed the object like it supposed to be. The error is literally: "this is undefined", so I expect the OptionGroup array.

**Rendered if machine is set:**

```
<div *ngIf="machine">
    <app-option-selector [inputMachine]="machine"></app-option-selector>
</div>
```

**Component with function:**

```
export class OptionSelectorComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() inputMachine: Machine;
  options: Option[];
  optionGroups: OptionGroup[];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.options = this.inputMachine.Options;
    this.setOptionGroups();

  }

  setOptionGroups(){
    this.options.forEach(function(e){
      console.log(e.OptionGroup);
      this.optionGroups.push(new OptionGroup())
    })
  }
}
```

So is there an Angular way to create such sorting? Not prone to errors, like I tried to do?

Comment: Use the [sort function](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/sort)

Comment: *this gave an undefined error,*: which has nothing to do with Angular. You're trying to push option groups into `this.optionGroups`, but you never initialized `this.optionGroups`, so it's undefined.

Comment: `optionGroups: OptionGroup[] = [];` is initialization right? But it gives the same error.

Comment: And the error is? And the line that the error points to is?

Comment: I guess you’re in another scope in the `forEach` loop, so you can’t use `this`. You should use an arrow function instead inside `forEach`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.options = this.inputMachine.Options;
    this.optionGroups = this.setOptionGroups();
  }

setOptionGroups() {
  const optionsCopy = [...options]; // don't mutate options array
  this.optionsCopy.sort((a, b) => (
    // your sort logic
    a.Id - b.Id // example : order by id
  ));
  return optionsCopy.map(option => new OptionGroup() {
    id: option.Id
  });
}
```

Comment: What does the map function do in the end?

Comment: [Map documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) : it returns a new array. We use it to create an array of `OptionGroup` from `optionsCopy` which is an array of `Option`.

Comment: Okay thanks for your help and time! I'm going to make a combination of the posts and will make an update with answer to this question by today.

Answer (score 1):

You can group by attribute:

```
arrayToObject(array, keyField) {
    return array.reduce((obj, item) => {
        obj[item[keyField]] = item;
        return obj;
    }, {});
}
```

Usage:

```
const groups = this.arrayToObject(this.options, 'OptionGroup');
       this.optionGroups = Object.values(groups);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help and time this is almost the function I needed, I'm going to make a combination of the answer posts and will update the answer by today.

Answer (score 1):

You could use lodash

```
    const machines: Machine[] = [/*...*/];
    const options: Option[][] = machines.map(machine => machine.options);
    const flatOptions: Option[] = [].concat(...options); // could also use lodash flatten
    const optionGroups: OptionGroup[] = flatOptions.map(option => option.optionGroup); 
    const uniqueOptionGroups: OptionGroup[] = _.uniq(optionGroups); // import * as _ from 'lodash'
```

And for the sort itself

```
machines.forEach(machine =>
      machine.options.sort((option1, option2) =>
        // your compare
      );
    );
```

Comment: Thanks I've read some documentation of Lodash, seems like an interesting library! Definitely going to try it out.

Comment: Yeah it serves some interesting utility. You don't need to to learn it. Just in case you want to write some util functions in your application just check if there is the same util available in lodash. It mostly is.